# StackOverflow Careers - Internship + Co-op shows as Internship on profile

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I'm interested in Co-op positions (I'm assuming it means the same as Joint Venture?), but when I select that option, it only shows internship on my profile.

[image]

[image]

Maybe add Co-op / Joint Venture as a separate option?